# How to implement Nuget Package Restore In Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, msbuild, nuget, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

After I follow this tutorial: http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/package-restore/team-build, I found 2 main issues or concerns:

1. When I am using Azure Cloud, my build process template will be **Azure Continuous Deployment Template** instead of using the **Default Template**, and this has a *Solution to Build* property instead of *Projects* so when you replace the `.sln` with `build.proj`, the build will generate an exception: `"Exception Message: Please specify a Visual Studio Solution (.sln) to build. (type BuildFromSolutionException)"`
2. Other issue that I maybe will face later is: how to specify my own nuget package sources? I may have additional sources beside https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

**Default Template**
[image: Default Template]
**Azure Continuous Deployment Template**
[image: Azure Continuous Deployment Template]

Comment: If you need multiple nuget sources, add an additional package source in nuget.config

Comment: I don't like the idea since Nuget v2.7+ recommends to get rid off those nuget files... but if I have to use it, it is not a problem... my main concern is problem #1.

Comment: No, NuGet 2.7+ recommends that you don't use MSBuild-based package restore with NuGet.targets. nuget.config is perfectly valid.

Comment: Where do you specify this in the new ASP.NET 5 / NuGet 3.0 project.json file format? Can't seem to find an equivalent to add a package restore source so that Azure knows how to pull dependencies from different repos

Comment: I could never get nuget package restore working with the templates in Visual Studio. I spent many many days on it, asking questions on stackoverflow, reading blogs etc. It just did not work. Thankfully these templates have been deprecated in favor of online templates through the VSTS portal.